# How can I link the author of a post two his profile page with django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to link the author of a post two his profile page, but when I click the on the link, get refered two /profiles/ not to the id of the author.

My views.py looks like this:

```
def userpage(request, id):
    profil = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=id)
    context = {'profil': profil}
    return render(request, 'gaestebuch/userpage.html', context)
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.userpage, name='userpage')
```

And the html part where I want to have the link looks like this:

```
{% for e in latest_eintrage_list %}
        <li>
           <div id="comment_main">
--->           <a href="{% url 'gaestebuch:userpage' profil.id %}">{{ e.author }}</a>
           <br>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'gaestebuch:result' e.id %}">{{ e.title }}</a>
        <br>
        <div id="comment_main">
           Comments: {{ e.comments.count }} | {{ e.created_date }} | {{ e.get_typ_display }}
        </div>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
           <hr>
        {% endif %}
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The part marked with an arrow is the part, where I wanted the link to the author to be.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = False, default=('keine Angabe'))


class Eintrag(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    NEED = 'ND'
    GIVE = 'GV'
    TYP_CHOICES = (
        (NEED, 'Need'),
        (GIVE, 'Give'),
)

typ = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices= TYP_CHOICES, default=NEED)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I am receving the following error-message:

```
Reverse for 'userpage' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'gaestebuch/profiles/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

I am glad for any help :)

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: What is `profil` in your last snippet?..

Comment: This is the error message: Reverse for 'userpage' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'gaestebuch/profiles/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: I thought that I have to use the profile defined in my view, since I did the same with the link to the post.  I am new two django, so I kind of guessed it.

Comment: Is the bottom the html of `userpage.html` or something else? What have you tried/researched to solve the problem so far? The error message has plenty of duplicates

Comment: Double check that `profil.id` is actually defined by rendering `{{ profil.id }}` in your template. I suspect it won't appear

Comment: As @gtlambert says, `profil` is not defined inside your `{% for e in latest_eintrage_list %}` loop. It looks like you want a different `profil` for each loop, rather than passing a `profil` from the view to the template context. However, you haven't shown your models, so we can't say how to get from an `eintrag` to a `profil`.

Comment: Yes the I wanted to link it to userpage.html. The error seems to be in the template.

Comment: Oh sry, I will put my model in the describtion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `{% for e in latest_eintrage_list %}` loop, you do have a variable `profil`. Therefore `profil.id` is treated as the empty string, and the url tag fails.

You can follow the foreign key from `Eintrag.author` foreign key to the `User` model, then follow the one to one field backwards to the `UserProfile` model:

```
<a href="{% url 'gaestebuch:userpage' e.author.userprofile.id %}">{{ e.author }}</a>
```